# 64 bit Multiplier in Fpga

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have written a code for a 64 bit multiplier using four parts splitting technique. The device used is vertex 6. The code contains 4 16*16 multipliers and 6 17*17 signed multipliers. total 10 multipliers. but the summary after synthesize tells me that 16 DSP slices have been used, which i must restrict to 10. Could anyone please help me to show how to decrease the number of DSP slices used here. Following is my code.

```
'module mul64(a,b,clk,c);

input [63:0] a,b;
input clk;
output reg [127:0] c;


wire [31:0] pp0,pp1,pp2,pp3;

reg signed [16:0] a32,b32,a31,b31,a30,b30,a21,b21,a20,b20,a10,b10;

reg signed [33:0] p32,p31,p30,p21,p20,p10;

reg [33:0] s1,s2,s4,s5;
reg [33:0] s3;

reg [49:0] ppr1;
reg [65:0] ppr2;
reg [81:0] ppr3;
reg [97:0] ppr4;
reg [113:0] ppr5;
reg [127:0] ppr6;

// 16*16 multipliers
mul16 a1 (a[15:0],b[15:0],clk,pp0);
mul16 a2 (a[31:16],b[31:16],clk,pp1);
mul16 a3 (a[47:32],b[47:32],clk,pp2);
mul16 a4 (a[63:48],b[63:48],clk,pp3);

always @ (posedge clk)
begin

a32 <= a[63:48]-a[47:32];
b32 <= b[63:48]-b[47:32];
a31 <= a[63:48]-a[31:16];
b31 <= b[63:48]-b[31:16];
a30 <= a[63:48]-a[15:0];
b30 <= b[63:48]-b[15:0];
a21 <= a[47:32]-a[31:16];
b21 <= b[47:32]-b[31:16];
a20 <= a[47:32]-a[15:0];
b20 <= b[47:32]-b[15:0];
a10 <= a[31:16]-a[15:0];
b10 <= b[31:16]-b[15:0];

// 17*17 signed multipliers
p32 <= a32*b32;
p31 <= a31*b31;
p30 <= a30*b30;
p21 <= a21*b21;
p20 <= a20*b20;
p10 <= a10*b10;

// partial products according to 4 parts splitting technique
s1 <= pp1+pp0-p10;
s2 <= pp2+pp1+pp0-p20;
s3 <= pp3+pp0-p30+pp2+pp1-p21;
s4 <= pp3+pp2+pp1-p31;
s5 <= pp3+pp2-p32;

// shifting of the partial products
ppr1 <= {s1,16'b0};
ppr2 <= {s2,32'b0};
ppr3 <= {s3,48'b0};
ppr4 <= {s4,64'b0};
ppr5 <= {s5,80'b0};
ppr6 <= {pp3,96'b0};

// sum of partial products
c <= pp0+ppr1+ppr2+ppr3+ppr4+ppr5+ppr6;

end

endmodule'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will use more DSP blocks than there are partial products, because you have wide addition in summing the partial products, as well as multiplication. You can more efficiently create wide multipliers using cascaded DSP blocks, as explained in [Xilinx UG389](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug389.pdf), page 28 and 29.

Although this describes a 35x35 multiplier in a Spartan device, the same technique can be applied to wider multipliers in other devices. The resulting design should use only one DSP block for each partial product.